# What are some sources to learn projective geometry?

Tags: reference-request, elliptic-curves, projective-geometry

I am looking for notes, books etc. for learning projective geometry for getting started with elliptic curves.

Comment: Why do you think you need to know projective geometry to get started with elliptic curves?

Comment: The OP would do well learning a bit of projective geometry before getting started with elliptic curves.

Comment: @user101 in my book on "Elliptic curves, modular forms, and L-functions", there is an appendix on projective geometry. It is not much, but it covers the very basics you need for elliptic curves. However, a source like Fischer (below) would contain a lot more background material to be comfortable working in projective coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Elliptic Tales](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Elliptic-Tales-Curves-Counting-Number/dp/0691163502/ref=mp_s_a_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1545173252&sr=8-1&pi=AC_SX236_SY340_FMwebp_QL65&keywords=elliptic%20tales&dpPl=1&dpID=514pbH53qmL&ref=plSrch). Very good.

Answer (score 1):

C. Fischer, "Plane Algebraic Curves", AMS Student Mathematical Library, 2011.

It seems to have a lot of introductory material on projective geometry and algebraic curves.